# Samsung SCX-4623fw toner cartridge in dell 1135n Laser MFP

Tags: printer, compatibility, firmware, toner

I've got a Dell 1135n Laser MFP and Toner Cartridge for Samsung SCX-4623fw. The Dell 1135 is a rebranded Samsung SCX-4623fw.

When inserting the cartridge the printer says "Toner cartridge is not compatible. Check user's guide". Well obviously that is a lie. They are perfectly compatible, but Dell wants me to buy their Cartridge.

I have tried googling for Samsung firmware that I could install on the Dell, but couldn't find any firmware at all.

Is there any other way in which I could make the printer accept any toner cartridge?

Comment: even if you could change the firmware on the Dell, is it worth the effort for one cartridge?  Also, there is no guarantee that the two different models of printers are *exactly* identical.  You could end up damaging the printer.

Comment: @Keltari its not just one cartridge really. The Samsung cartridges are cheaper... The printers are really identical.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the chip from Samsung to Dell. You can buy toner reset chips to suit Dell 1130 1130n 1133 1135 1135n on eBay

Answer (score -1):

I am not  sure if this will work but worth trying out:

- Try turning of the ink level tracking feature on your printer driver
  software. That should take care of the problem, if not try next

  Uninstall Dell printer driver software, and then re-install again but
  this time choose custom re-installation option and make sure you do
  not install ink-level tracking (or anything to do with ink tracking
  on your printer soft ware). 99% of the time this should take care of the problem.

Comment: this wont work.  The printer is reading the chip on the toner cartridge.  The driver or software on the PC are irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think doing anything with the Drivers on the workstation will have effect at all. When I print something the Driver doesn't complain. It sends it to the print just fine. The printer will refuse to print it. It will even refuse to copy anything.